# How do I convert this into a shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

Can you provide a MWE of modularized shiny code that uses renderUI? I'd like an example to follow.

There is an excellent tutorial that discusses this here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html however, it doesn't show how to integrate the modularization of renderUI components in the ui nor in the server.

Here's what I've tried so far:

In my ui code, I had:

```
  htmlOutput("selectionUI")
```

In my server code, I had:

```
  output$selectionUI <- renderUI({
    req(input$Filter)
    selectInput(
      inputId = "Selection",
      label = "Selection",
      choices = get("qlist", envir = get(input$source))[[input$Filter]]$responses)
  })
```

Now I would like to modularize this becuase it's a sometimes repeated element, but I'm not sure how to actually insert it into my ui/server code once I'm done.

Here's what I've tried:

```
selectionChooserUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('controls'))
}

selectionChooser <- function(input, output, session, data, sourcedata, filter) {
  output$selectionUI <- renderUI({
    req(input$Filter)
    ns <- session$ns
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns('Selection'),
      label = 'Selection',
      choices = get('qlist', envir = get(input[[sourcedata()]]))[[input[[filter()]]]]$responses
    )
  })
}
```

What do I have to put into my ui code to get it to diplay, currently I'm getting complaints that `"output" is missing with no default`?

I'm calling it presently in my ui code, using:

```
selectionChooserUI("selection")
```

Comment: You named your `output` as `controls` in `selectionChooserUI`. So it should be `output$controls` at `selectionChooser`.

Comment: And I think you should use `filter()` instead of `input$Filter` and `input[[filter()]]`.

Comment: Thanks @user5029763 I made those change and it resulted in the same error. `Error: argument 'output' is missing with no default`

Comment: How are you calling at server-side? Check the `callModule`

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clearer what I'm looking for. If you know how to frame up a MWE of modularized renderUI, please submit it as an answer and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably something like this. I haven't test it out since I don't have your data ..

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Get me a Module!"),
  selectInput("source", "Some source", choices = letters[1:4]),
  selectInput("filter", "Some filter", choices = letters[1:4]),
  selectionChooserUI("id_of_me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_me_choices <- reactive({
    get("qlist", envir = get(req(input$source)))[[req(input$filter)]]$responses })

  callModule(module = selectionChooser, id = "id_of_me", choices = get_me_choices)
}

selectionChooserUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('selection'))
}

selectionChooser <- function(input, output, session, choices) {
  ns <- session$ns

  output$selection <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns('selection'),
      label = 'Selection',
      choices = choices
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Did this help you with modularizing your app?